# How to randomly select one row off table based on critera

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-ce

This is in Microsoft SQL Server CE, I have the following table

TABLE

```
[ID]  [eventID]  [factString]
```

I am trying to randomly select the `factString` off of one row from the above table where the `eventID` equals a specific number.

```
 (randomly) 
 SELECT factString 
 FROM factTable 
 WHERE eventID = 1
```

That is to say, if there are 10 rows where the `eventID` is 1, I want to return one row which is random every time.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add ORDER BY Rand()

```
 SELECT factString 
 FROM factTable 
 WHERE eventID = 1 
 ORDER BY Rand()
```

And LIMIT 1 for only 1 row

Answer (score 0):

If you just want 1 row, you should add `top 1` in SQL.

```
SELECT TOP 1 factString 
FROM factTable 
WHERE eventID = 1 
ORDER BY Rand()
```